# How to install a tagged commit from a local Git repository using Composer?

Tags: git, tags, dependencies, repository, composer-php

I'd like to install a specific tag from a local Git repository using Composer.

That is what I got in my composer.json:

```
{
    ...,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@192.168.1.24:vendor/project.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "vendor/project": "dev-master#v2.5.0"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Problem is that Composer just installs the latest commit, not the one which is referenced by the given tag. The tags are all set up in the local Git repository. The local repository (vendor/project) also has a composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/project",
    "version": "master",
    "dist": {
        "url": "git@192.168.1.24:vendor/project.git",
        "type": "git"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it's tag why dont yo try to put only tag without dev-master

Comment: I think I tried that without success.

Comment: have you heard of satis?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `v2.5.0` tag, you just have to use `2.5.0` (or better, a range like `2.5.*`).

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that. Thanks so far. I will try and report back as soon as possible. :)

Comment: Tried it, but it's always checking out the latest commit instead of the version.